# Setting Graphics rendering level like ArcMap UniqueValueRenderer in ArcGIS AP for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology

I have to add a Map Layer on Map which I am able render with UniqueValueRenderer. After rendering I want to have certain value matching graphics always on Top if they are over lapping. But I am not able to set Like we set symbol levels  in ArcMap.

```
    let green = new DirectionalLineSymbol({ style: SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, color: new Color([50, 200, 20,1]), width: 5, directionSymbol: 'arrowf', directionSize: 20, directionPixelBuffer: 50, showStartSymbol: false });
              let yellowf = new DirectionalLineSymbol({ style: SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, color: new Color([255, 210, 2, 1]), width: 5, directionSymbol: 'arrowf', directionSize: 20, directionPixelBuffer: 50, showStartSymbol: false });
              let yellowr = new DirectionalLineSymbol({ style: SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, color: new Color([255, 210, 2, 1]), width: 5, directionSymbol: 'arrowf', directionSize: 20, directionPixelBuffer: 50, showStartSymbol: false });
              let red = new DirectionalLineSymbol({ style: SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, color: new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.7]), width: 5, directionSymbol: 'arrowf', directionSize: 20, directionPixelBuffer: 50, showStartSymbol: false });
              let renderer = new UniqueValueRenderer(green, function (graphic) {
                  if (segments.find(e => e.objectid == graphic.attributes.OBJECTID && !e._deleted && !e.is_reverse)) {
                      graphic.setSymbol(yellowf);
                      return 'YELLOW_F'
                  }
                  else if (segments.find(e => e.objectid == graphic.attributes.OBJECTID && !e._deleted && e.is_reverse)) {
                      graphic.setSymbol(yellowr);
                      return 'YELLOW_R'
                  }
                  else if (segments.find(e => e._deleted == true && graphic.attributes.OBJECTID == e.objectid)) {
                      graphic.setSymbol(red);
                      return 'RED'
                  }
                  else if (graphic.attributes.MAINT_RD_TRIM && graphic.attributes.RDWAY_ID) {
                      graphic.setSymbol(green);
                      return 'GREEN'
                  }
                  else {
                      graphic.setSymbol(red);
                      return 'RED'
                  }
              })
              //get data fro m layer manually and sort and add to the map to fix road  on top 
              renderer.addValue({ value: 'GREEN', symbol: green, label: 'Valid Segments' ,level :3})
              renderer.addValue({ value: 'RED', symbol: red, label: 'Invalid Segments' ,level :2});
              renderer.addValue({ value: 'YELLOW_F', symbol: yellowf, label: 'Selected Segments',level :1  })
              renderer.addValue({ value: 'YELLOW_R', symbol: yellowf, label: 'Selected Segments' ,level :0})//changed from yellowr
              layer.setRenderer(renderer);
```

though above code snippet I am able to render graphic in red, yellow green but I want Yellow color graphics always on TOP which is not happening. I did not find any thing in API Documentation too.

[image]